# How to associate a nsg to app service environment to restrict access from internet in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I wanted to restrict access from internet to my app service environment, such that only my front end app service can only access it. Is there a possible way to do it?.

[image]

As shown in the above picture I wanted to associate an NSG to tier 2 such that only tier 1 can access tier 2. Nobody else can access it. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Developers can use IP and Domain Restrictions to control the set of IP addresses, and address ranges, that are either allowed or denied access to their websites. With Windows Azure Web Sites developers can enable/disable the feature, as well as customize its behavior, using web.config files located in their website

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity>
                <add ipAddress="x.x.x.x" allowed="false" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

If a request is made to a website from an address outside of the allowed IP address range, then an HTTP 404 not found error is returned as defined in the denyAction attribute.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/forced-tunnel-support

Comment: <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity>
                <add ipAddress="x.x.x.x" allowed="false" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>


Hi there, this is the code for restricting a single IP address Right?. I wanted to deny all the IP addresses  and allow only one IP address. May I know how to write the code for achieving it?.